# PHP Array Index/splice

Tags: php, arrays, array-splice

I'm using PHP 5.4 (and no I can't upgrade to something newer). I'm trying to find the index of an element in an array, but I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong since when I call `array_splice()` I'm getting an illegal string offset error.

I'm running a SQL query, and then pushing each row onto the array. I'm then trying to find the index of one of the row's attributes. When I don't use `array_splice()` and I just push the rows on I have no errors when I go to print out specific attributes of each array entry.

---

EDIT:

```
print_r(array[i]):

Array (
  [comment_id] => 0
  [reply_to] => 0
  [username] => user0
  [comment] => comment0
)
```

I want to find where comment_id equals a certain value and then insert a new record at array[i+1].

---

The relevant PHP code snippet:

```
$comment_array = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       $new_sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE reply_to = " . $row["comment_id"] . " AND reply_to != comment_id";
       $new_result = $conn->query($new_sql);
       //array_push($comment_array, $row);
       if ($new_result->num_rows > 0) {
          if($row["reply_to"] >= $row["comment_id"]){
              array_push($comment_array, $row);
          }
                                              
          while($new_row = $new_result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $index = -1; 
              foreach($comment_array as $key => $val){
                  if ($val['comment_id'] == $new_row["reply_to"]) {
                    $index = $key;
                    break;
                  }
              }
              if($index > -1){
                  array_splice($comment_array, $index, 0, $new_row);
              } else {
                  array_push($comment_array, $new_row);
              }
           }
       } else if($row["reply_to"] == $row["comment_id"]){ 
           array_push($comment_array, $row);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you really using PHP 4.0? What database library are you using? It looks like mysqli but that wasn't available until PHP 5.

Comment: I thought I could've sworn I was using 4 since that was listed, but I must have misread it. Apparently I'm running 5.4, but array_column was throwing an error (which is what originally made me assume I was running something older). Well, since I'm running 5.4, any suggestions as to how I could find the index of something in the array and how to insert right after it?

Comment: @djd97 can you provide a sample array and output you want ? Update in the question

Comment: I have a mysql database with three columns (id, parent, text). I get a record and push that record onto my array exactly as is (so however a record with three columns would be formatted...I'm assuming three keys referring to three values). And I'm trying to find a specific parent key and then add a new record right after the index that contains the parent key attribute. (I updated my post)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you just want a comment thread?

Comment: yes, although I would still like to know why I'm getting an error with what I have.

Answer (score 0):

you're pretty close, your array_split actually inserts your array at `array[i - 1]` not `array[i + 1]`. to actually insert it at `array[i+1]` you can do

```php
              $needleIndex = null;
              $needlePlusOneIndex = null;
              $needlePlusTwoIndex = null;
              foreach($comment_array as $key => $val){
                  if($needlePlusOneIndex !== null){
                      $needlePlusTwoIndex = $key;
                      break;
                  }
                  if($needleIndex !== null){
                      $needlePlusOneIndex = $key;
                      continue;
                  }
                  if ($val['comment_id'] == $new_row["reply_to"]) {
                    $needleIndex = $key;
                  }
              }
             if($needlePlusTwoIndex !== null){
                  array_splice($comment_array, $needlePlusTwoIndex, 0, $new_row);
              } else {
                  array_push($comment_array, $new_row);
              }
```

because $needlePlusTwoIndex is what array_splice needs to insert it at array[index + 1] (your original code insert it at index-1 and using $needlePlusOneIndex would insert it at index and $needlePlusTwoIndex will insert it at index+1)